# JavaScript callback without changing scope?

Tags: javascript

I try to learn javascript and therefore I tried the following code:

```
function repeat(n, action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        action();
    }
}
function benchmark() {
    var start = [], end = [], timings = [];
    repeat(1000, function() {
        start.push(Date.now());
        // Repeat something
        end.push(Date.now());
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < end.length; i++) {
        timings[i] = end[i] - start[i];
    }

    return timings;
}
```

My Question now: Why can I access start and end in my callback? As I understood the scope changed from benchmark to repeat. Is the callback a closure or is a closure onle a defined named function in another function?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: @Pawel possible duplicate of my comment ;) ;)

Comment: @Mik378: true, you was faster some seconds :-)

Answer (score 0):

In short - your callback is nested inside `benchmark` which means it has access to the variables within the closure of `benchmark`. `repeat` is not nested within `benchmark` and thus does not have access to the variables in the closure of `benchmark`.

Comment: But when I would access a variable with "this" in the closure, then the scope changed?

Comment: `this` refers to the immediate function in which it is used - thereby `this` used in first line of `benchmark` would not refer to the same as `this`used in the first line of `repeat`.

Comment: But why would this.startin benchmark() not points to the same as var start = [];

Comment: `this` is the object corresponding to the function `benchmark` and would not be accesible to inner functions in `benchmark` where as a variable declared inside `benchmark` like e.g. `var start = 'something'` would be accesible inside an inner function.

Answer (score 0):

To understand that you have to understand the concept of [*closure*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29).

> Closures are typically implemented with a special data structure that
>   contains a pointer to the function code, plus a representation of the
>   function's lexical environment (i.e., the set of available variables)
>   at the time when the closure was created

In your case, the callback which is invoked in repeat (*action*) is a closure and in it's lexical environment you have start, end, timings and all the available global variables.

Answer (score 0):

But when I would access a variable with "this" in the closure, then the scope changed? And what happen if I initialize via this.start = []; an array in the first line of repeat function?